# Selected row on top in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik MVC Grid and I want the selected to be forced on top of the list.  I´m using DetailedView for the grid so it is collapse- and expandable.  How would I force the selected row to the top of the list?

**My Jquery:**

```
function unit_onDetailViewExpand(e) {
    // Select the Grid
    var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
    //Close all other rows
    grid.$rows().not(e.masterRow).each(function (index, row) {
        grid.collapseRow(row);
    });

    /* TODO: move row to the top, this hasn´t worked for me so far
    grid.reorderColumn(0, grid.columnFromTitle("Name"));
    $.telerik.trigger(grid.element, 'repaint');
    */
}
```

Thanx guys  :)

**#### EDITED ####**

This is what I do now when selecting the row:

```
function onRowSelect(e) {
    $(e.row).prependTo($(e.row).parent());
    var grid = $('#RentableUnits').data("tGrid");
    // get the first master table row
    var tr = $("#RentableUnits tbody > .t-master-row:eq(0)"); // use .t-master-row to select only the master rows

    // expand the row
    grid.expandRow(tr);
}
```

Now I´m faced with the problem that the content of the DetailedView has not moved.  Let´s say I select a row, the row moves to the top, expands the row, but the content of the previous row is still expanding.

I´ve been looking at the [**documentation**](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnDetailViewExpand) and found out that this has something to do with detailRow, but I can´t figure out how to move that along with my masterRow.

Does anyone have any idea on how to move the content of the detailedview along with the row?

**#### EDITED (AGAIN) ####**

I´ve gotten so far, the table row is moved to the top of the list but every time that particular row is expanded I keep getting the content of the original top row (the content from the one which is in second place).  From what I see in Firebug is that there are no .t-detail-row within the table until one of the .t-master-row is expanded.  Should I move something else along with the selected row, I mean other that the masterRow and sometimes the detailRow?

(I´ve also uploaded images along with the question showing HTML from Firebug)

```
function onRowSelect(e) {
    var grid = $('#RentableUnits').data("tGrid");

    var selectedRow = $('#RentableUnits tbody>.t-state-selected');
    selectedRow.prependTo(selectedRow.parent());
    if (selectedRow.next().is('.t-detail-row')) {
        selectedRow.next().prependTo(selectedRow.parent());
    }
    selectedRow.prependTo(selectedRow.parent());

    // get the first master table row
    var tr = $("#RentableUnits tbody > .t-master-row:eq(0)"); // use .t-master-row to select only the master rows
    // expand the row
    grid.expandRow(tr);
}
```

You´ve been a great help to me, maybe I can bug one more time?  :)

#

[image: Page Load, the rows are correct]

#

[image: Row selected and the wrong detail-content is loaded (the same as the first row was)]

#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Grid component has underlying data.
You need to position data item that is represented by selected row as well.

```
function on_RowSelect(e){

    var grid = $(e.target).data('tGrid');
    var $rows = grid.$rows();

    // move underlying data
    var rowIndex = $rows.index(e.row);
    grid.data.unshift(grid.data.splice(rowIndex,1)[0])

    // move rows
    var $selectedRows = $(e.row).add($(e.row).next('.t-detail-row'));
    $rows.parent().prepend($selectedRows);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Wow!!! that worked!  Thank you veeeery much mr @Rustam you saved me a lot of trouble  :)  I wouldn´t have imagined the idea to use unshift() function and splice them together.  Sincearly thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily move the selected row to the top when needed with the following script:

```
var selectedRow=  $('#GridName tbody>.t-state-selected'); 
selectedRow.prependTo(selectedRow.parent())
```

Please notice that you can change the selector to be more generic if needed - use class name or use search context to find the selected row.

Or you can also even use the **[onRowSelect](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnRowSelect)** event to execute your logic like this:

```
function onRowSelect(e){
    $(e.row).prependTo($(e.row).parent());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Pechka, your code works to move the row to the top.  However I´m facing another problem at the moment.  I´m using DetailedView and when I move the row to the top I still expand the old content within each row.  If I were to move one row to the top, then expand it, the content of the "old" row is still there as the expanded content.  Any ideas?

Comment: I see, then you can do the following. If the next element after the row you selected is a detail row move it to the top of the Grid and then move the row itself to the top. This way you will keep the structure of the Grid valid and when you expand it the detail row will be just under the first row as you would expect.

e.g.
var selectedRow=  $('#GridName tbody>.t-state-selected'); 
selectedRow.prependTo(selectedRow.parent());
if(selectedRow.next().is('.t-detail-row')){
    selectedRow.next().prependTo(selectedRow.parent())
}
selectedRow.prependTo(selectedRow.parent())

Comment: Thank you for that @Pechka, you´ve been a great help.  Perhaps I could bother you some more?  I´ve edited my question again.

Comment: I also uploaded images that I snipped from Firebug, just to show the HTML markup as I select the row  :)